# unexpected token with a layout

Tags: java, android, layout

i'm new here and I and new into android developping too. I Have a problem with a layout that doesn't want to compile. here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>"

</LinearLayout>

<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:layout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    layout:width="match_parent"
    layout:height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the error is at the "LinearLayout" lines it says "unexpected tokens". I have modified this file manually, I have perhaps modified something that have break my file.

Comment: Check below answer .Starting wrong tag

Answer (score 3):

You have a closing tag in your second line. Make it an opening tag by changing

```
</LinearLayout>
```

to

```
<LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>"
<LinearLayout>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:layout="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    layout:width="match_parent"
    layout:height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You didn't have proper opening tags.  was present instead of  in line number 2.

Comment: Your screenshot shows an ``"`` at the end of the first line. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the opening tags of linear layout. It needs to be look like that.

```
//Opening tag <LinearLayout     // Closing tag </LinearLayout>
```